# Not getting solution for gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: android, json, retrofit, gson

I hope you could give me a hand on a Gson issue I can't solve. It is quiet common apparently since I found many topic on this subject, but didn't manage to use answers.

I have this error :

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

**Model class**

```
public class User {

        @SerializedName("status")
        @Expose
        private String status;
        @SerializedName("result")
        @Expose
        private Boolean result;
        @SerializedName("user")
        @Expose
        private User_ user;

        public String getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(String status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        public Boolean getResult() {
            return result;
        }

        public void setResult(Boolean result) {
            this.result = result;
        }

        public User_ getUser() {
            return user;
        }

        public void setUser(User_ user) {
            this.user = user;
        }
        public class User_ {

            @SerializedName("ID")
            @Expose
            private String iD;
            @SerializedName("user_login")
            @Expose
            private String userLogin;
            @SerializedName("user_nicename")
            @Expose
            private String userNicename;
            @SerializedName("user_email")
            @Expose
            private String userEmail;
            @SerializedName("user_url")
            @Expose
            private String userUrl;
            @SerializedName("user_registered")
            @Expose
            private String userRegistered;
            @SerializedName("user_activation_key")
            @Expose
            private String userActivationKey;
            @SerializedName("user_status")
            @Expose
            private String userStatus;
            @SerializedName("display_name")
            @Expose
            private String displayName;
            @SerializedName("avatar")
            @Expose
            private String avatar;
            @SerializedName("first_name")
            @Expose
            private String firstName;
            @SerializedName("last_name")
            @Expose
            private String lastName;

            public String getID() {
                return iD;
            }

            public void setID(String iD) {
                this.iD = iD;
            }

            public String getUserLogin() {
                return userLogin;
            }

            public void setUserLogin(String userLogin) {
                this.userLogin = userLogin;
            }

            public String getUserNicename() {
                return userNicename;
            }

            public void setUserNicename(String userNicename) {
                this.userNicename = userNicename;
            }

            public String getUserEmail() {
                return userEmail;
            }


            public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
                this.userEmail = userEmail;
            }

            public String getUserUrl() {
                return userUrl;
            }

            public void setUserUrl(String userUrl) {
                this.userUrl = userUrl;
            }

            public String getUserRegistered() {
                return userRegistered;
            }

            public void setUserRegistered(String userRegistered) {
                this.userRegistered = userRegistered;
            }

            public String getUserActivationKey() {
                return userActivationKey;
            }

            public void setUserActivationKey(String userActivationKey) {
                this.userActivationKey = userActivationKey;
            }

            public String getUserStatus() {
                return userStatus;
            }

            public void setUserStatus(String userStatus) {
                this.userStatus = userStatus;
            }

            public String getDisplayName() {
                return displayName;
            }

            public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
                this.displayName = displayName;
            }

            public String getAvatar() {
                return avatar;
            }

            public void setAvatar(String avatar) {
                this.avatar = avatar;
            }

            public String getFirstName() {
                return firstName;
            }

            public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
                this.firstName = firstName;
            }

            public String getLastName() {
                return lastName;
            }

            public void setLastName(String lastName) {
                this.lastName = lastName;
            }

        }



    }
```

**api interface**

```
interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("userauth/userlogin")

    Call<User> getUser(@QueryMap Map<String, String> params);
}
```

**API client**

```
public class ApiClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://caribbeanhomenetwork.com/api/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(client)
                .build();



        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

**Main Activity**

```
 Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
       params.put("username", email);
       params.put("token",new String(android.util.Base64.encode(token.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT)));
       params.put("password",password);


 Call<User> call = apiInterface.getUser(params);
       call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {

               User user= new Gson().fromJson(String.valueOf(response), User.class);
               Log.e("TAG",user+"");
               User resource = response.body();
               Log.e("resource........",resource.getStatus());
               if(resource.getStatus().equals("ok")){
                   ActivityUtils.getInstance().invokeActivity(mActivity, MainActivity.class, true);
               }



           }

           @Override
           public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
               call.cancel();
               Log.e("error.....","........"+t);
           }
       });
```

**JSON**

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "result": true,
  "user": {
    "ID": "1",
    "user_login": "admin",
    "user_nicename": "admin",
    "user_email": "vijay.webnware@gmail.com",
    "user_url": "",
    "user_registered": "2017-08-03 07:43:57",
    "user_activation_key": "",
    "user_status": "0",
    "display_name": "admin",
    "avatar": "",
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
    "wp_capabilities": {
      "administrator": true,
      "wpcf_custom_post_type_view": true,
      "wpcf_custom_post_type_edit": true,
      "wpcf_custom_post_type_edit_others": true,
      "wpcf_custom_taxonomy_view": true,
      "wpcf_custom_taxonomy_edit": true,
      "wpcf_custom_taxonomy_edit_others": true,
      "wpcf_custom_field_view": true,
      "wpcf_custom_field_edit": true,
      "wpcf_custom_field_edit_others": true,
      "wpcf_user_meta_field_view": true,
      "wpcf_user_meta_field_edit": true,
      "wpcf_user_meta_field_edit_others": true
    },
    "membership_levels": [

    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: First thing change User_ class to nested static class @user

Comment: Can you post the Json that triggers this error please?

Comment: Please use response.getBody().toString(). You are currently just converting response object to string.